# Any good "contact us" recipes for Cherrypy?

Tags: python, cherrypy, contactus

I'm looking to implement a "Contact Us" form with Cherrypy and was wondering: Is there a good recipe (or a BSD licensed set of code) that I could use instead of reinventing the wheel?

Ideally, this would be Cherrpy 3.1 compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I had to look into a solution.  This works (ugly, and w/o Javascript validation) -- using the smtplib lib.  Also, note that I stole Jeff's captcha for this example.  Anyone using this will need to change it.

**EDIT:** I added validation.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.4 
import smtplib 
import cherrypy

class InputExample:
   @cherrypy.expose
   def index(self):
       return "<html><head></head><body><a href="contactus">Contact Us</a></body></html>"


        @cherrypy.expose
        def contactus(self,message=''):
                return """
<html>
<head><title>Contact Us</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function isNotEmpty(elem)
   {
      var str = elem.value;
      var re = /.+/;
      if (!str.match(re))
      {
         elem.focus();
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         return true;
      }

   }

   function isEMailAddr(elem)
   {
      var str = elem.value;
      var re = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/;
      if (!str.match(re))
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

   function validateForm(form)
   {
      if (isNotEmpty(form.firstName) && isNotEmpty(form.lastName))
      {
         if (isNotEmpty(form.email))
         {
         if (isEMailAddr(form.email))
         {
            if (isNotEmpty(form.captcha))
            {
               if ( form.captcha.value=='egnaro'.split("").reverse().join(""))
               {
                   if (isNotEmpty(form.subject))
                     {
                        alert("All required fields are found.  We will respond shortly.");
                        return true;
                     }
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("Please enter the word as displayed in the image.");
                   return false;
               }
            }//captcha empty
            }
         else
         {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            return false;
         } //email
         } //email
      } //first and last name
      alert("Please fill in all required fields.");
      return false;
   }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>%(message)s</p>
<form method='POST' action='contactUsSubmitted' onsubmit='return validateForm(this)'>
   <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
   <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" /> (required)<br/>
   <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
   <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" /> (required)<br/>
   <label for="email">E-mail address: </label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /> (required)<br/>
  <label for="phone">Phone number: </label>
   <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /> <br/><br/>

   <!--THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED TO MATCH YOUR OWN CAPTCHA SCHEME!! -->
   <label for="captcha">Enter the word<br /><img alt="rhymes with.." src="http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/word.png" width="99" height="26" border="0" /></label><br />
(<a href="http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/sounds/captcha-word-spoken.mp3">hear it spoken</a>)<br />
   <input tabindex="3" id="captcha" name="captcha" /><br /><br />

   <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
   <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" /> (required)<br/>
   <label for="body">Details: </label>
   <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea><br/>

<input type='submit' value='Contact Us' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
"""%{'message':message}


        @cherrypy.expose
        def contactUsSubmitted(self, firstName, lastName, email, phone, captcha, subject, body ):
                if captcha[::-1] != 'egnaro':
                        return self.contactus("Please reenter the word you see in the image." )
                self.sendEmail('mail2.example.com','mailbox_account','mailbox_pwd','me@example.com',email,
                     'Website Contact: '+subject, 'Sender Email: ' + email + '\r\n'
                     'Name: ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '\r\n' + 'Phone: ' + phone + '\r\n' + body)
                return self.index()

        def sendEmail(self,smtpServer, mailboxName, mailboxPassword, contactEmail,senderEmail,subject,body):
                server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer) #'smtp1.example.com')
                server.login(mailboxName, mailboxPassword)

                msg = "To: %(contactEmail)s\r\nFrom: %(senderEmail)s\r\nSubject: %(subject)s\r\nContent-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n%(body)s"
                msg = msg%{'contactEmail':contactEmail,'senderEmail':mailboxName + '@example.com','subject':subject,'body':body}

                server.sendmail(contactEmail, contactEmail, msg) #This is to send it from an internal account to another internal account.
                server.quit()


cherrypy.root = InputExample()
cherrypy.config.update ( file = 'development.conf' )
cherrypy.server.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize the question is four years old, but for those still searching:

I recommend using the python library [Marrow Mailer](https://github.com/marrow/marrow.mailer). It abstracts the whole smtp vs sendmail, etc., and also provides excellent server-side validation. The code is under the MIT license (which is BSD-esque and GPL compatible), which is what you were looking for. The readme on github provides examples on how to use. The library is compatible with Python 2.6+ and 3.1+.

Marrow Mailer, combined with the answer by *torial*, provides a simple "contact us" form for CherryPy/python. I've found [Voluptuous](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) to be a very simple validator (that you can use for the form server side; BSD license), or the WIP [Validator](https://github.com/wilhelm-murdoch/Validator). There's also several Javascript/jQuery plugins for validating client side (such as http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).